# Unequal grid lines thickness in exported graphics

Tags: export, rendering, grid-lines

When I export plots with gridlines as images, both as .jpg and .png, some of the lines are much thicker than the others. In *Mathematica* they all have the same thickness. How can I solve this problem?

Simple example:

```
plot = Plot[Exp[-(x^2/2)], {x, -4, 4}, ImageSize -> 1000, GridLines -> Automatic]
Export["plot.jpg", plot]
```

Then I get the following exported image (see the line at -4):
[image]

I have the same problem for `ListPlot` as well and using various options for the plots, such as `Axes->False`, `Frame->True`, various aspect ratios...

I use *Mathematica* 11.0.1.0, platform Linux x86 (64-bit) (on CentOS7)

Comment: I see no such problem in my MMA 11.0.1. May be it is because of some graphic settings, I'm not sure though!

Comment: I use MMA 11.0.1 on Windows 10 and I see no problem on the exported image.

Comment: No such problem on Mma 11.0.1, Mac OS X 10.11.

Comment: I have no such problem with MMa 11.0.1 on Win7 x64. A side note: it is always a bad idea to use a lossy format like JPG for exporting such type of graphics, use PNG instead.

Comment: I can add that exporting as .svg works fine, but in my case that would lead to huge files so that is not an option.

Comment: It is indeed a bug. Have you reported this to the tech support?

Comment: Alexey, no, I have not, but if you agree that it might be a bug I'll do that.

Comment: Just tried this with version 11.0.1, also on CentOS7 and the .jpg image comes out fine...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After consulting the Mathematica support, which could not reproduce this issue given the same version of Mathematica on the same OS, I was asked to try the following:

- Resetting Mathematica ($ mathematica -cleanstart )
- Running with mesa drivers ($ mathematica -mesa )
- Using Image[] to render the image before exporting.

Using Image[] solved the issue, but not the other options. I did not try reinstalling.